# BootsFaces DataTable onSelect(var,typeOfSelection,indexes) works but generates javascript network errors

Tags: datatable, bootsfaces

xhtml ===========================================+=====================

```
<b:dataTable id="feedTable"
  value="#{mainfeed.records}" 
  var="record"
  style="border-style: none; margin-top: 40px; width: 100%; overflow-y: scroll;"
  pageLength="1000"
  paginated="false"                       
  searching="false"
  fixedHeader="true"
  select="true"
  selectionMode="single"
  selectedItems="rows"
  onerror="#{mainfeed.onError()}"
  onselect="ajax:mainfeed.onSelect(record, typeOfSelection, indexes);"
  oncomplete="$('.modalPseudoClass2').modal();"
  span="12"
  info="false"
  scrollCollapse="false"
  tooltip="Score = 1&#215;views + 10&#215;comments + 2&#215;pluses + 2&#215;minuses"
  update="bmodal"
  >    
    
  <b:dataTableColumn label="Title" width="70%" style="border-style: none; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;" orderable="true" dataOrder="record.value.Author" >
  <h:outputText value="#{record.value.Title}" style="font-size: small; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; alignment-baseline: middle;" />
    <br/>
    <b:container>
      <h:outputText value="#{record.value.Author}" style="padding-left: 10px; font-size: smaller;" />
      <h:outputText value="#{record.value.Timestamp}" style="padding-left: 10px; font-size: smaller; color: lightgrey" />
    </b:container>
  </b:dataTableColumn>
```

mainfeed.java ==========================================================================

```
private String title = "";
public String getPreviewTitle() {
    return title;
}

private String preview = "";
public String getPreviewText() {
    return preview;
}

public void onSelect(DataFeed feed, String typeOfSelection, String indexes) {
  if (feed instanceof DataFeed) {
    DataClass test = new DataClass();
    test.setKeyName(feed.getValue("source"));
    try (Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost")) {
      test.readPartial(jedis, feed.getValue("Source"), new String[] {"Persistent", "Folder", "Text"});
      jedis.close();
    }            
    title =  feed.getValue("Title", "Selected");
    preview = test.getValue("Text", "").replace("<br/>", "");
    preview = preview.length() > 128 ? preview.substring(0, 128) : preview;
    System.out.println("selected");
  }
}
```

The onSelect handler executes and contains all data. But after it completes a "Error in evaluated javascript:A network error occurred" is reported, then another "Error in evaluated javascript:A network error occurred." with a "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs", and then another.

I have been trying to trace it down but can't find anything. Any suggestions on where I should look.

Comment: By switching the mode from DEVELOPMENT to PRODUCTION I was able to see the following network errors in a browser.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js. (Reason: header ‘content-type’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response). There were many more errors of this type.

Comment: Reason: missing token ‘xyz’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel url: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowHeaderFromPreflight